# Stata's permute and weighted regression

Tags: stata, weighted-regression, permutation-test

I want to do a permutation test for a command where I'm using weights. E.g.:

```
 permute treatment _b[treatment]: reg y x treatment [pweight=w]
```

`permute` doesn't allow for weights, but can be `force`d to ignore that. The help-file only has the vague statement that: "`permute` is not suited for weighted estimation, thus `permute` should not be used with weights or `svy`".

Is anyone here able to explain why weights might be problematic for permutation tests?

Comment: Cross-posted at [Statalist](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1353621-using-permute-on-a-command-with-weights).

Comment: This is true. Is that a problem?

Comment: It is considered polite to let people know on most fora, and required at Statalist. It keeps people from answering questions that already have answers and wasting their time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permutation tests do resampling from the observed units in the dataset, or in the subsample selected (if using `if` statements). As such:

- they could perfectly accommodate frequency weights `[fweight]`. First, the command should internally expand the sample (process which is unequivocal, as there is just one expanded sample). Then, it should do permutation from that expanded sample. THerefore, it is a limitation of the **command** and not of the theory that frequency weights are not allowed. Actually, a trivial workaround in this setting is to expand the sample yourself (using `expand fweight_varname`) and then run the permutation test. If you do this, you can also use `preserve`...`restore` to avoid creating a huge dataset. In any case, this confirms that the `permute` test could easily implement frequency weights.
- in principle, they could also accommodate sampling weights `[pweight]`. The difference is more theoretical than anything. Sampling weights often come from a probabilistic analysis (e.g. a regression), and as such, they are random variables, with a distribution. In consequence, it is quite a strong assumption that those weights do in fact represent with certainty a given population, which is the case under permutation tests. However, this could again be easily implemented, as **informally** you can transform `pweight` into `fweight` (which is hardly a good advice anyway). I imagine this is why `permute` does not accept sampling weights.

**Note** however that the fact that `force` is available might be an indication that Stata programmers know these options are possible, but do not want to assert a method that they might think is not always robust, leaving to the researcher the task of proving that robustness.

Interestingly, the same is true for `bootstrap`. It "does not" accept weights, although the `force` option is there.